# Set height and width for responsive chart using recharts ( Barchart )

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, recharts

I am trying to use recharts to implement a BarChart. But the `width={600}` and `height={300}` causes the Barchart to be absolute, not responsive. How to make the Barchart a responsive one? I tried using percentage as `width={'50%"} height={"40%"}` but did not work.

```
import { BarChart, Bar, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend } from 'recharts';


<BarChart className="barChart" width={600} height={300} data={data}
          margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}} label="heaf">
      <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
      <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
      <YAxis/>
      <Tooltip/>
      <Legend />
      <Bar dataKey="occupied" barSize={10} fill="#05386b" />
      <Bar dataKey="available" barSize={10} fill="#fdaa00" />
      <Bar dataKey="cleaning" barSize={10} fill="#379583" />
      <Bar dataKey="reserved" barSize={10} fill="#c60505" />
</BarChart>
```

Comment: All solutions here only work for width—did you get it working for height as well? All the provided answers all have a fixed height.

Answer (score 79):

You need to use `ResponsiveContainer` for it to work. Also, use the percentage values **without** brackets.

```js
<ResponsiveContainer width="95%" height={400}>
   // your chart
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

I used that and it worked just fine! :)
Source: [Responsive Container Docs](http://recharts.org/en-US/api/ResponsiveContainer)

Comment: I tried to put the height as a % but it doesn't work. same for you ?

Comment: this is a fixed-height

Answer (score 28):

You can use `ResponsiveContainer` provided by `recharts`.

[Docs](http://recharts.org/en-US/api/ResponsiveContainer) of `ResponsiveContainer` says:

> A container component to make charts adapt to the size of the parent container. One of the props width and height should be a percentage string.

Here is the working code https://codesandbox.io/s/react-recharts-responsive-stack-overflow-863bi. Try resizing the output window width:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  BarChart,
  Bar,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  ResponsiveContainer
} from "recharts";

import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  { name: "Page A", uv: 4000, pv: 2400, amt: 2400 },
  { name: "Page B", uv: 3000, pv: 1398, amt: 2210 },
  { name: "Page C", uv: 2000, pv: 9800, amt: 2290 },
  { name: "Page D", uv: 2780, pv: 3908, amt: 2000 },
  { name: "Page E", uv: 1890, pv: 4800, amt: 2181 },
  { name: "Page F", uv: 2390, pv: 3800, amt: 2500 },
  { name: "Page G", uv: 3490, pv: 4300, amt: 2100 }
];

const SimpleAreaChart = () => {
  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer>
      <BarChart data={data} margin={{ top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5 }}>
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <XAxis dataKey="name" />
        <YAxis />
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend />
        <Bar dataKey="pv" fill="#8884d8" />
        <Bar dataKey="uv" fill="#82ca9d" />
      </BarChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("container");
ReactDOM.render(<SimpleAreaChart />, rootElement);
```

Here is the css of `container`:

```
#container {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: How can I do this with when using a class based component

Answer (score 7):

If you want both of the dimension to scale, just use `aspect` property

```
<ResponsiveContainer aspect={1.2}>
   // chart with width = 1.2 height
</ResponsiveContainer>

<ResponsiveContainer aspect={0.8}>
   // chart with width = 0.8 height
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

The height / width will be 100% of the parent container in this case.

Comment: Thank you -- I had been looking for exactly this type of approach! Every example I've seen requires explicitly setting the height and/or width explicitly (if not for `<ResponsiveContainer>` then for a parent div), but `aspect` lets me just have the chart adjust to its parent's size, regardless of whatever else is happening.

Comment: Thank you! Why isn't this more commonly known?? I've been looking for this solution for like days now!

Comment: It took me a while to find this too :) Sometimes you actually need to force yourself to read documentation :D

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the bar chart with divs.

```
<div style={{ position: 'relative', width: '50%', paddingTop: '40%' }}>
  <div style={{ position: 'absolute', height: '100%' }}>
    <BarChart />
  </div>
</div>
```

for outer div: width of 50% is with respect to the container width. paddingTop is 40% of the container width.

for inner div: height of 100% will occupy its entire container whose height is only its paddingTop.

Comment: I tried a couple of variations of this in my react app, and I couldn't get the BarChart to render.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="95%" height={data.length*x}>
```

data.length -> number of components in y axis

x -> size of cell to increase (33 worked well in my case)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to require a specific aspect ratio, nor did I want to require one of the dimensions to be fixed, so I decided to dynamically set the height and width of the chart by querying a parent container's size and width using `use-react`'s `useMeasure` hook.

```js
const [chartRef, chartDimensions] = useMeasure()

return (
  <div ref={chartRef}>
    <LineChart
      width={chartDimensions.width}
      height={chartDimensions.height}
      ...
    >
    {/* chart components here */}
    </LineChart>
  </div>
)
```

I wanted my chart to always fill this div that's able to be resized in any way by the window.

Answer (score 0):

Give **minWidth** and **height** to the **ResponsiveContainer Wrapper**. ***Simple as that***

```
import {ResponsiveContainer} from "recharts";

//make sure to wrap minWidth in {} and not in ""
<ResponsiveContainer minWidth={350} height={350}>
    <BarChart className="barChart" data={data}>
    </BarChart>
 </ResponsiveContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using breakpoints with Tailwind CSS

If you're using Tailwind CSS, another option is to wrap your chart in the `ResponsiveContainer` component, leave the `height` and `width` properties unset, and pass various breakpoints to the `className` property.

The advantage of using media breakpoints is that it lets you specify different min height (or width) based on screen size. The `ResponsiveContainer` that `rechart` provides is great at responsively resizing in one direction, but a fixed height of 350px on a large screen winds up stretching the chart out.

For those who haven't used Tailwind CSS, here's the documentation on using [responsive breakpoints](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#responsive-breakpoints) and more information about [sizing utility classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/min-height).

#### Sample component

The example below highlights how you can pass tailwind-style media breakpoints to the `ResponsiveContainer.className` property, which will let you responsively resize your chart based on the screen size.

```
import { Bar, BarChart, ResponsiveContainer, XAxis, YAxis } from "recharts";

export interface BarChartProps {
  data: Array<Object>;
  labelKey: string;
  valueKey: string;
}

export function ResponsiveBarChart({ data, labelKey, valueKey }: BarChartProps) {
  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer className="min-h-40 md:min-h-80"> // notice the md: breakpoint
      <BarChart data={data}>
        <XAxis
          dataKey={labelKey}
          stroke="#888888"
          fontSize={12}
          tickLine={false}
          axisLine={false}
        />
        <YAxis
          stroke="#888888"
          fontSize={12}
          tickLine={false}
          axisLine={false}
          tickFormatter={(value) => `$${value}`}
        />
        <Bar
          dataKey={valueKey}
          fill="currentColor"
          radius={[4, 4, 0, 0]}
          className="fill-primary"
        />
      </BarChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
}
```

#### Sample usage

Here's an example of how you could use this chart component in various sized containers:

```
import { ResponsiveBarChart } from "./components/bar-chart"

const data = [
  {
    day: "Monday",
    total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000) + 1000,
  },
  {
    day: "Tuesday",
    total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000) + 1000,
  },
  {
    day: "Wednesday",
    total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000) + 1000,
  },
  {
    day: "Thursday",
    total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000) + 1000,
  },
  {
    day: "Friday",
    total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000) + 1000,
  },
];

function Dashboard() {
  <section id="dashboard">
    <div className="grid gap-4 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-8">
      <div className="col-span-4 rounded-lg border shadow-sm p-4 pt-6">
        <ResponsiveBarChart
          data={data}
          valueKey={"day"}
          labelKey={"total"}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="col-span-4 rounded-lg border shadow-sm p-4 pt-6">
        <ResponsiveBarChart
          data={data}
          valueKey={"day"}
          labelKey={"total"}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="flex rounded-lg border shadow-sm p-4 pt-6">
      <ResponsiveBarChart
        data={data}
        valueKey={"day"}
        labelKey={"total"}
      />
    </div>
  </section>;
}
```

#### Sample output

The resulting "dashboard" should look something like this on desktop:

[image]

And something like this on mobile:

[image]